# How to find last element in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection name Users in Mongo DB Atlas.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ebe6fdc9f17193b6c51063e"},"name":"Harry","country":"India","gender":"male"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"6fbe6fdc9f17193b6c52463e"},"name":"John","country":"Africa","gender":"male"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"7gbe6fdc9f17193b6c58063e"},"name":"Mike","country":"USA","gender":"male"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"8hbe6fdc9f17193b6c53063e"},"name":"Alice","country":"India","gender":"female"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"9ebe6fdc9f17193b6c52063e"},"name":"Katherine","country":"UK","gender":"female"}
```

and its goes on.

What query can be used in node.js and mongoose to find last element in the collection?
How I can get the id of the last element of the collection when the collection keeps on increasing dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your `_id` as `ObjectId` type, you can sort by `_id` and the sorting order will be in order of creation.

```
items.find().sort([['_id', -1]] ) // get all items desc by created date.
```

And if you want the last created item, you can use the following query:

```
items.find().sort( [['_id', -1]]).limit(1) // get last created item
```

In essence, ordering by "_id" will order by creation date.